# Hosting ASP.NET Core application on shared Linux hosting

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, shared-hosting

Now asp.net core has been released so we can develop/deploy .net application on any platform.

I am trying to play with asp.net core and able to run my application on ubantu os(On Virtual Machine). But i just wanted to hosted dot net core application on shared linux hosting environment where simply upload published file.

I was following [Tony's blog](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/), to play with core.

We need DNVM, DNU and DNX to run application, but we don't have terminal to execute these commands on shared hosting.

Help me figure out the solution.

Comment: DNVM/DNU/DNX are all dead with ASP.NET 5. Please pay enough attention to https://docs.asp.net to study the true ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for suggestion, I explored [asp.net documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html), as per link we just need to copy and paste deployed application on server and its done.Actually I don't have any shared hosting server right now and I will try soon. If i am missing something then please suggest me.

Comment: Hi @MarkSpencer, me also prefer windows hosting but tradition is changing and microsoft is also supporting linux then why we don't use linux hosting. As per my knowledge azure also provide linux hosting. there are few point to consider linux hosting. 1- msft released asp.net core for any platform. 2- linux hosting is cheaper then windows hosting. 3- linux is one of the secured OS. 4- Some client is prefer linux hosting.

Comment: haha, @MarkSpencer cost doesn't matter some time but we cannot ignore Linux hosting. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Hi, have you had any luck with running dot net core on a shared Linux host?

Comment: @CaseyC585, I tried many times but didn't get success :( . I investigated and discussed with hosting companies. But they are not offering such kind of facility now.

Comment: I wouldn't expect many shared hosting companies to offer .NET Core hosting.  If you're looking to run ASP.NET Core on Linux I did write a blog on Hosting on Ubuntu on Digital Ocean - https://www.tonyranieri.com/blog/2017/10/27/Hosting-.Net-Core-On-Linux/  The advice there should apply to most VM hosts (Azure, AWS, Linode, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is somewhat possible... and actually, Scott Hanselman just did it using .NET Core 2.1 (still in preview, although). He got it running on GoDaddy's shared Linux plan. You may follow his step by step [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RunningASPNETCoreOnGoDaddysCheapestSharedLinuxHostingDontTryThisAtHome.aspx), but you are strongly adviced not to do it.

Comment: I love this evil hack, really awesome hack . Thanks scott.

Comment: why this is not the recommended way. Any specifiy drawback

Comment: @user3036876 it is hacky, it won't work everywhere (will depend on the host's configuration) and might be against the terms of use.